# Whats i should know to make my nodejs server public with no dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux

I am trying to learn how to do things without using dependencies, I know it will probably take a long time but the point is to learn the basics, what do I need to know to host my server on my machine and be able to share a url with my friends? It can be topics for me to search

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `http` built in module to make a server and then set up port forwarding I'm your router, just go to your router up address in your address bar, login, find the settings for port forwarding etc look up tutorials for it, then you can share that IP address and port with the entire universe